# Call function after an Intent is finished

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I think this is a simple problem, but can't find an answer.
I got this piece of code:

```
 public void onButtonClick(View v) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(root + "/Doppen/"+ "doppen.txt");
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);                   
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, getIntent());
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){
        System.out.println("RESULT :D");
    }
}
```

Got any idea what is wrong here?

I open a text file, but after the user tapped on "Save", I want to call an other function.
How to do this automatically?
So how to check when user taps on "Save" or when the intent is done/finished?

**EDIT 1:**
I found a problem:
When I comment `if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==1){` then it does print the result when it is done, So I know where it goes wrong, now the why question :p

**EDIT 2:**

requestCode does prints "1", so that is good. However, resultCode prints "0", not good.

**EDIT 3:**

Found the answer, maybe also usefull for others.
After I pressed Save, I use the backbutton (of the phone) to get back to the app, but that gives a resultCode of "0".

Comment: Try adding "@Override" before `onActivityResult`.

Comment: @jmhend thanks for the reply, but didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity()`.  When the activity completes, you'll get a callback to your activity's `onActivityResult()` method, where you can do what you need.

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more information.

---

EDIT:  `RESULT_OK` is a standard result code, but activities are free to return other values greater than or equal to `RESULT_FIRST_USER`.  Zero is `RESULT_CANCELED`, which usually happens when someone whacks the Back button.

Comment: Could you check my question again (changed it slightly), I tried this (also used internet example) but I can't seem to get it to work :(